# Just eval first symbol (CHICKEN Scheme)

Tags: scheme, eval, chicken-scheme

How can I evaluate an s-expression only by the first term?

```
(define (fn x y) (print x) (print y))
(eval '(fn a b))
```

I am trying to evaluate something like this on a bigger expression but the interpreter is complaining that `a` and `b` variables don't exist (*unbound variable a*).

Is there something I can do to leave symbols as they are?

I have been trying to find information about this but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: `(fn 'a 'b)`? :)

Comment: Thanks but initially I need the list of symbols, from there I will be evaluating deep into the function. Eval could be perfect because the function will then be evaluating the next symbols as functions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following?

```
(let ((expr '(fn a b)))
  (cons (eval (car expr)) (cdr expr)))
```

But please note that if you have to rely on `eval`, you're almost certainly doing things wrong.

Comment: By the way, you might get more direct responses if you ask on IRC; we're in `#chicken` on Freenode.

Comment: thanks yes my solution was very much like this `(define (evals x) (apply (eval (car x)) (cdr x)))`